# How to create hyperlinks in vim notes?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[This is the note taking plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-notes) in question. I tried using the traditional markdown syntax [displayed text](link here) but it's not working. It is highlighting urls when given like http://vim.org but I can't get it do it in markdown style.

Comment: The plugin doesn't support that.

Comment: the plugin seems can export as markdown

Comment: @svlasov but in the demo, there is a link where the text displayed is different from the link. If you put the cursor on the link, the url is displayed. That's why I expect there to be some way to give hyperlinks.

Comment: It only hides the protocol, like `https://`.

Comment: @svlasov bummer :( If you post an answer, I will accept

Comment: @ma08, I finally have a better solution, check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `.vim/after/syntax/notes.vim` with:

```
syn region urlTitle matchgroup=mkdDelimiter start="\[" end="\]" oneline concealends nextgroup=urlRef
syn region urlRef matchgroup=mkdDelimiter start="(" end=")" oneline conceal contained

hi link urlTitle notesRealURL
hi link urlRef notesRealURL
```